# How to lock screen Orientation in QML 2?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am developing QML app for Microsoft Surface 3/4 and I need to lock the orientation to portrait. I was expecting a setOrientation() for `QScreen/Screen` component in QML/QT but I am not finding any API.

I am using QT 5.9.1.Please suggest.

Comment: I don't think qml has anything on that, for android and ios it is done externally, probably the same case for windows.

Comment: Yes I found lot of examples for Android and iOS .. is there anyway to do in Windows externally ?

Comment: You can just live with the screen rotation, let your self be informed by watching the `Screen`-properties and counter the rotation by setting a rotation on  your root item. This should work for all OS the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . I will try !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dtech answer will also work and there is a way to do this without linking `user32.lib`. Just copy paste below code in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <Windows.h>

typedef enum ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE {

    ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_NONE              = 0x0,

    ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE         = 0x1,

    ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT          = 0x2,

    ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE_FLIPPED = 0x4,

    ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT_FLIPPED  = 0x8
} ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE;

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *pSDARP)(ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE orientation);

pSDARP pARP;
pARP = (pSDARP) GetProcAddress( GetModuleHandle(TEXT("user32.dll")),  "SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences");

if( pARP ){

    pARP( (ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE)(ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE | ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_LANDSCAPE_FLIPPED ) );
}
```

For more information please refer : [Handling Windows Auto-rotate feature in your application](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/10/handling-windows-8-auto-rotate-feature-in-your-application)

Answer (score 2):

Qt doesn't offer anything on that, which IMO is an important omission. You are left with relying on how different systems handle that. Fortunately, it is quite easy for windows. You can use the windows API to set it for the current process in main.cpp:

```
// includes
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h> 
#endif

// in main()
#ifdef _WIN32
SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences(ORIENTATION_PREFERENCE_PORTRAIT);
#endif
```

You will also have to link your project against `User32.lib` or `User32.dll` to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is possible externally (never tried, look into @dtech answer).

> Information for ***"expecting a setOrientation() for QScreen/Screen
>   component in QML/QT"***

Using `QScreen` it is not possible.

Look into the documentation of QScreen properties.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#details

All the properties related to orientation like "***nativeorientaion***","***orientation***" and "***primaryorientation***", they all are `CONSTANT` properties.

And the QT property system says that, the Constant property can not have WRITE capability:

**The presence of the CONSTANT attibute indicates that the property value is constant. For a given object instance, the READ method of a constant property must return the same value every time it is called. This constant value may be different for different instances of the object. A constant property cannot have a WRITE method or a NOTIFY signal.**

Comment: @dtech in the question he also asks about "expecting a setOrientation() for QScreen/Screen component ".... My answer is to address that point

Comment: @dtech i can delete it, if it is not informative and useful. Please let me know